# Were Tony Stark's robots in the Iron Man movies inspired by Red Dwarf's scutters?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, red-dwarf

I was watching Iron Man 3 recently and it occurred to me that the robots Tony Starks uses in his workshop look an awful lot like the scutters from Red Dwarf.

Is there any evidence that the Iron Man robots were inspired by Red Dwarf?

### Scutter (from Red Dwarf)

[image: A Scutter from Red Dwarf]

### Tony Stark's Robot Arm

[image]

Comment: They look a lot more like standard industrial arm robots available today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any evidence that the Iron Man robots were inspired by Red Dwarf?

**We can't prove a negative** but it seems unlikely.

The two "robots" in question are usually referred to a "Dummy" and "U" have a striking resemblance to standard industrial robotic arms in use across the industrialised world.

[image]

Inustrial robots have been in existence for decades, the first "example" per [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_robot#Types_and_features) being in 1938.

If anything the Scutters and the Iron Man examples are both based on old standard designs.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it wasn't likely, but I *really* wanted it to be true :-)